# Data sent as undefined unable to find the reason in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, express, redux

In the forgot password file in am collecting the email where i have to send the recovery link. I got the email as input and doing console.log shows me the email that i got.
Next i dispatched the email and sent the email to backend for generating the recovery link however at backend it shows that the link is undefined and i don't know neither can figure out the reason behind it. If someone could help i would be really grateful.

this is the forgotpasswordreducer

```
export const forgotPasswordReducer = (state={},action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST:
    case RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading:true,
        ...state,
        error:null,
      }
    case FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS:
      return{
        ...state,
        loading:false,
        message:action.payload,
      };
    case RESET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading:false,
        success:action.payload,
      };
    case FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL:
    case RESET_PASSWORD_FAIL:
      return{
        ...state,
        loading:false,
        error:action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error:null,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

this is the forgotpassword action

```
export const forgotPassword = (email) => async(dispatch) => {
    try{
        dispatch({
            type:FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST,
        })

        const config = {
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            }
        }
        
        const {data} = await axios.post(`/api/v1/password/forgot`,email,config);

        dispatch({
            type:FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
            payload:data.message,
        })

    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({
            type:FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL,
            payload:error.response.data.message,
        })
    }
}
```

and this is the file where i am taking the input of the email from the user

```
import React, { Fragment , useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import "./ForgotPassword.css";
import MailOutLineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MailOutline";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader.js";
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {useAlert} from "react-alert";
import {clearErrors,forgotPassword} from "../../actions/userActions";

const ForgotPassword = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const alert = useAlert();
    const {error,message,loading} = useSelector((state)=>state.forgotPassword);
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");

    const forgotPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const myForm = new FormData();
        myForm.set("email",email);
        dispatch(forgotPassword(myForm));
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(error){
            alert.error(error);
            dispatch(clearErrors());
        }
        if(message){
            alert.success(message);
        }
    },[dispatch,error,alert,message]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
        {loading?(
        <Loader/>
    ):
    (
    <Fragment>
        <MetaData title="Forgot Password"/>
        <div className="forgotPasswordContainer">
            <div className="forgotPasswordBox">
                <h2 className="forgotPasswordHeading">Forgot Password</h2>
                <form className="forgotPasswordForm" onSubmit={forgotPasswordSubmit}>
                    <div className="forgotPasswordSubmit">
                        <MailOutLineIcon/>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required name="email" value={email} onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit"
                    value="Send"
                    className="forgotPasswordBtn"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Fragment>) }
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default ForgotPassword;
```

this is the userController file  of the backend

here when i try to console.log the req.body.email i am getting undefined.

```
exports.forgotPassword = catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body.email);
    const user = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email});
     
    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found",404));
    }

    // get reset password token 

    const resetToken = user.getResetPasswordToken();

    // saving the user to save the token of the user that was generated

    await user.save({validateBeforeSave:false});

    const resetPasswordUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/api/v1/password/reset/${resetToken}`

    const message = `Your password reset token is :- \n\n ${resetPasswordUrl} \n\n If you have not requested this email then please ignore it.`;

    try{    

        await sendEmail({
            email:user.email,
            subject:`Ecommerce Password Recovery`,
            message,
        });

        res.status(200).json({
            success:true,
            message:`Email was sent to ${user.email} successfully`,
        });

    }
    catch(error){
        // if their is some kind of error we would remove the token that was generated and also 
        // make the expire time of the token to be the current time.
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;
        await user.save({validateBeforeSave:false});
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message,500));
    }
});
```

Can someone please help me figure out why this is happening. If more code snippet or file is required for solving the error please let me know ill attach them aswell.

Trying to figure out why the data is not being passed after taking it's input from the form in react-redux. It shows that the email taken as input is undefined and i can't figure out the reason behind it.

Comment: In the `forgotPassword` action creator what is the value of `email`? In the POST request, is the request body what you expect going to the backend? In the backend on that endpoint, is the body value still what you expect?

Comment: @DrewReese the value that i am receiving at the backend is undefined. i want the result to be the email that was entered in the form but i don't know why everything that I set in the myForm object is shown to be undefined.

Comment: Even in the user Actions file if i try to print the email it shows as undefined... that means that the email is not even going to the useraction file. I think it is somewhat realated to the FormData that i have used but i can't understand what i have done wrong.

Comment: You don't appear to be passing JSON data to that endpoint, try `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` in the request header. Do you know what/how the backend endpoint is expecting the body to be encoded? What is the endpoint expecting to receive?

Comment: @DrewReese i tried doing the multipart/form-data it is still not woking.

Comment: However when i tried doing      
     const myForm = {};
    myForm['email']=email;
    dispatch(forgotPassword(myForm)) 
it works this way

Comment: I still don't know the reason why i will attach the backend controller file as well. The backend file is expecting an object with the attribute of email.

Comment: Sounds like it's expecting JSON data. Just pass the Javascript object, e.g. `dispatch(forgotPassword({ email }))`, and let Axios JSON stringify the body payload then.

Comment: @drew reese how do i mark your solution as correct in the comment. I created a normal javascript object and it worked. I still don't why it was not working with FormData() object of javascript but it work's with other normal objects. Thankyou for your time drew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing form data to the `forgotPassword` action which makes a POST request via `axios`. For `axios` you have specified however that you are passing JSON data.

```js
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json" // <-- JSON data
  }
};
        
const { data } = await axios.post("/api/v1/password/forgot", email, config);
```

You *could* use `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` to send form data, but the backend would also need to be configured to receive this type of request body.

It sounds like your backend it just expecting JSON data however. Instead of passing a `FormData` object you could pass a Javascript object and let `axios` handle JSON stringifying the body payload.

```js
export const forgotPassword = (body) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type:FORGOT_PASSWORD_REQUEST });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
        
    const { data } = await axios.post("/api/v1/password/forgot", body, config);

    dispatch({
      type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.message,
    });
  } catch(error) {
    dispatch({
      type: FORGOT_PASSWORD_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

```js
const forgotPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dispatch(forgotPassword({ email }));
};
```